# Two questions regarding a script to find "Pythagorean Triplets"

Tags: python

The goal of the code is to find all "Pythagorean Triples" till the number n and have them in in a set of touples eg: {(3, 4, 5), (8, 6, 10)} . It doesn´t need to be the most efficient, but it shouldn´t include duplicates and the triplets should be ordered, so (3, 4, 5) and not (4, 3, 5). Basically in asending order.

This is the code I wrote:

```
triangles = set(frozenset((a, b, c))
                for a in range(1, 21)
                for b in range(1, 21)
                for c in range(1, 21)
                if a ** 2 + b ** 2 == c ** 2)

for d in triangles:
    print(tuple(d), end=" ")
```

Question 1 : 
Does frozenset() in line 1 remove all duplicates because the touples (3, 4, 5) and (4, 3, 5) are made equal, by making them sets, and are therefore one is "removed" (of course not really removed) when they are put in a set? If yes, is the first one in the set the one ***not*** "removed"?

Question 2 :
Why does the codes output include a touple like (8, 10, 6), which is a Pythagorean Triplet, but doesn´t mach the if statement in line 5?

Comment: It is important to remember that collections are out of order and that the order does not remain the same when type conversions are performed.`tuple({6,8,10})` will return `(8, 10, 6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm usually for using all the features of a language to make things easier, I'm not convinced that's what the assignment (if it *is* indeed an assignment) is trying to get you to do.

In a more conventional form (no sets, forcing you to learn algorithms rather than advanced language features), you can achieve ordered triplets with no duplicates, simply by ensuring the ranges are adjusted so that `c >= b >= a`:

```
pytrips = []
for a in range(1, 21):
    for b in range(a, 21):
        for c in range(b, 21):
            if a * a + b * b == c * c:
                pytrips.append([a, b, c])
for pytrip in pytrips:
    print(pytrip)
```

This outputs:

```
[3, 4, 5]
[5, 12, 13]
[6, 8, 10]
[8, 15, 17]
[9, 12, 15]
[12, 16, 20]
```

---

As an aside, I actually consider those "scaled" ones to be duplicates (`[6, 8, 10]` is simply a twice-as-big `[3, 4, 5]`). Your assignment may not share that same view, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is an example from a book for learning python and the chapter where this is from was all about sets and generators, so it was kind of "forced" to use the things learned in the chapter.